# Unable to read multiple set-cookie data using python requests Module

Tags: python, api, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to read all the cookies from the response using python requests module, but i am not able to read all set-cookies from the response. Is there any way to read all the things, I have tried a lot of things but nothing works
[click here for Image which contains two set-cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApMlI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When cookies are involved it's often ideal to utilize a  `requests.Session()` ([link](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/)). Sessions maintain all cookies for you, so you don't need to worry about grabbing them each time.

Example:

```
import requests

# Create a session
sess = requests.Session()

"""
Request whatever pages you want just like you normally would with requests.get & requests.post
"""
resp = sess.get('www....com')
```

Comment: Glad you got it working! If the solution worked for you please remember to mark it as answer.